# Xamarin Forms Pdf

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsidh.png)Hello,
      I'm preparing Pdf document and I want to print that document using Bluetooth printer, But the document format was not coming in the text format. it is in the metadata format, Can you please tell me how can I convert pdf document preview into image format or else how can I print pdf in document format. My pdf document format is like the below image. Can you please any one help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skCX4.jpg)

Comment: http://blog.apitron.com/2013/06/convert-pdf-to-image-csharp-dotnet-sample.html  check it's help for you

Comment: Tell me how to give print a pdf document to the bluetooth printer

Comment: check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3280/zebra-bluetooth-printers/p1